# Как изменить виджет темы bootstrap в symfony?

Tags: bootstrap, symfony, twig

Я использую для своего шаблона тему `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig`.
Хочу изменить виджет `submit` для конкретной страницы. Есть у меня вот такой html код для кнопки

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-anim"><i class="icon-rocket"></i><span class="btn-text">submit</span></button>
```

По документации я понял, что нужно переписать существующий виджет под себя.
Стянул со страницы на gihub

```
{% block button_widget -%}
    {%- set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('btn-default') ~ ' btn')|trim}) -%}
    {{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock button_widget %}
```

Начал с простого изменив `btn-default` на `btn-success`, по идее кнопка должна была изменить цвет на зеленый, но никаких изменений не произошло. Возможно есть какое нибудь более подробное руководство? И я так понимаю, чтобы добиться того результата как я приложил в html мне нужно изменить родителя? Прошу помощи в решении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В twig блоки работаю следующим образом. Выделяется блок в каком то из шаблонов, в Вашем случае `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` и вставляется код `twig + html`

```
{% block button_widget -%}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-anim"><i class="icon-rocket"></i><span class="btn-text">submit</span></button>
{%- endblock button_widget %}
```

если наследовать `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig`  в **другом** шаблоне `some1.html.twig` и вставить пустой блок `button_widget`:

```
{% extends "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" %}
{% block button_widget -%}{%- endblock button_widget %}
```

то выведется, то что внутри родительского блока, в нашем случае это кнопка:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-anim"><i class="icon-rocket"></i><span class="btn-text">submit</span></button>
```

Если же вы что то запишете внутри блока - это будет означать что вы переопределяете шаблон:

```
{% extends "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" %}
{% block button_widget -%}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">NEW SUBMIT</button>
{%- endblock button_widget %}
```

Вот тут тогда можно переопределить Вашу кнопку